# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-modules

This is the error I am facing:

```
/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:11
      const existing = channel.messages.cache.get(data.id);
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:11:41)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/ry/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ry/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/ry/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1047:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/ry/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:517:14)
```

This is the my code that I run.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var threads = [
  {
    channel: '498391317399863307',
    //interval: 1000 * 7200,
    message: 'hi'
  },
  {
    channel: '498391317399863307',
    //interval:  1000 * 7220,
    message: 'hello'
  },
  {
    channel: '498391317399863307',
    //interval: 1000 * 43200,
    message: 'bye'
  }
]


client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(Discord.version)
  for (i in threads)
  {
    function a(t, message) {
      client.channels.cache.get(t.channel).send(t.message).then(() => {
          let x = 1;
          if(t.message == "hi") {
            x = (Math.random() * ((1000*9000) - (1000*7200))) + 7200000; 
            console.log("hi: " + (x/1000) + " secs");
            
          } else if (t.message == "hello") {
            x = (Math.random() * ((1000*9900) - (1000*25000))) + 9000000; 
            console.log("\nHello: " + (x/1000) + " secs");

          } else if (t.message == "bye") {
            x = (Math.random() * ((1000*48600) - (1000*72000))) + 43200000; 
            console.log("\nBye: " + (x/1000) + " secs");
          }
          
        setTimeout(a, x, t)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
    }
    setTimeout(a, threads[i].interval, threads[i])
  }
});

client.login('');
```

Essentially the error given is not to do with my code itself.
I've tried also reinstalling discord.js but still no luck. (I am using Discord v12)
It works originally but every time throws that error so stops the whole thing.
I was wondering if anyone knows the solution for this issue. Thanks!

Edit: As I have received comments about where the error is from, as it shows the path is from the node_modules folder. I only have one js file which is the code I sent. I do not make the node_modules files.

However, here I have attached the MessageCreate.js which is found within the node_modules folder.

```
'use strict';

const Action = require('./Action');
const { Events } = require('../../util/Constants');

class MessageCreateAction extends Action {
  handle(data) {
    const client = this.client;
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id);
    if (channel) {
      const existing = channel.messages.cache.get(data.id);
      if (existing) return { message: existing };
      const message = channel.messages.add(data);
      const user = message.author;
      let member = message.member;
      channel.lastMessageID = data.id;
      if (user) {
        user.lastMessageID = data.id;
        user.lastMessageChannelID = channel.id;
      }
      if (member) {
        member.lastMessageID = data.id;
        member.lastMessageChannelID = channel.id;
      }

      /**
       * Emitted whenever a message is created.
       * @event Client#message
       * @param {Message} message The created message
       */
      client.emit(Events.MESSAGE_CREATE, message);
      return { message };
    }

    return {};
  }
}

module.exports = MessageCreateAction;
```

Comment: you didn't share your actually code which gives error. There's no `const existing = channel.messages.cache.get(data.id);` so you should share the file that shown on error `MessageCreate.js`.

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: The error message references a line that does not exist in the code that you posted. Furthermore, there is a syntax error (missing closing quote next to `hello`) so your code wouldn't even run! Please make sure the actual failing code.

Comment: Its in the console log and as mentioned in my description the error is not to do with my code and rather something else?
As you see in the error it shows the directory from node_modules.
This is the only js file I have, apart from within the node_modules.

Comment: Well, the error suggests `channel.messages` is `undefined` for the specific channel. Are you trying to use thread channels in discord.js v12? Because djs v12 does not properly support thread channels; it recognizes the channel, but it can't access the messages in the channel (probably why `channel.messages` is `undefined`). Consider updating to djs v13 or using some library that supports threads.

Comment: Hi, the discord channel is just a normal channel and not a thread channel.

Comment: Interesting. No clue what the problem is then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm receiving the same type of error on my bot now, while it was previously working fine for a long time.
You should take a look at the version of DiscordJS you're using. If it's < 13.3.1, consider upgrading - 13.3.1 contains the fix for this issue.

Comment: Hi, I decided to upgrade my DiscordJS and its working now. Was originally not planning to upgrade and did not need and did not know how it'll effect, but tried anyways and so far it seems all working. Thanks.

Comment: Same for me, but if Discord changed the way their API behaves, no other choice left for us.
Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the Discord Bot didn't get enough time to load all the channels, and you're trying to send a message to a channel that is not loaded yet. You if you don't want to update the Discord.js version, you can try adding some time to that message before sending it.

I'm not 100% sure, but in my case I added some time before sending the message and I haven't seen the same error again.