# What kinds of Discord channels trigger messageCreate but do not have channel.messages.cache? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

What kinds of Discord channels trigger messageCreate but do not have channel.messages.cache? (discord.js)

This is a followup to this question:

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077172/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-cache-discord-js)

I know the solution is to update discord.js but I would like to be able to reproduce the error using old versions of Discord, only for the sake of understanding.

Comment: you don't use `.cache` in discord.js v12

Comment: I don't use .cache but it's still in the discord.js source code, and caused errors in previous versions (before 13.3) see here: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js